# How to call method in base class in Perl

Tags: perl

## **#child.pm**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package child1;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter;
use parent;
my @ISA=qw(cal Exporter);
sub new{
        my $class=shift;
        my $ref=cal->new();
        bless ($ref,$class);
        return $ref;
        }
sub add{
        my $ref=shift;
        print "This is from child class";
        my($a,$b)=@_;
        return ($a+$b); 
        }
```

#**#parent.pm**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package cal;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter;
my @EXPORT=qw(add);
my @ISA=qw(Exporter EXPORT);
sub new{
        my $class=shift;
        my $ref=[];
        bless ($ref,$class);
        return $ref;
        }

sub add{
        my $ref=shift;
        my $a=shift;
        my $b=shift;
        return ($a+$b);
        }
1;
```

## **#test.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter;
use child;
my @ISA=qw(child1 Exporter);
my $obj=new child1();
my $sum=$obj->add(1,2);
print "$sum=sum";
```

**I am getting the error Can't locate object method "add" via package "child1" at ./test.pl line 8.**
I want to access the base class add method
and I am getting this above error

please clarify..

Comment: Where did you see that syntax? Are you working with a book or tutorial? To be frank, your code looks like it's 1998.

Comment: @innaM which syntax u r saying?..i am a beginner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .pm modules do not need, and likely do not want, the #!/usr/bin/perl lines. This is only for programs intended to be executed from the command line, like your .pl module. While you may 'perl -cw' your .pm modules, or do other command line debugging with them, such is not normal "production" use.

And .pl modules should not have @ISA, or other "our" declarations found in packages nor any exporter related things.

As said before, change "my"s for package stuff to "our"s. The "my" hides things to outsiders as if the statements were never there.

In the "cal" class, do you want something like the following? I favor SUPER as it really shows what is going on *and is much more generic*.

```perl
package child1;
use Exporter;
our @ISA=qw(cal Exporter);

sub new{
        my $class=shift;
        my $ref=<b>$class-&gt;SUPER::new()</b>;
        return $ref;
        }
```

One final point: you may need a "\n" on the final print statement. Without it the buffer may not flush correctly on exit in some environments so you will never see the output.

Comment: is there any syntax other than cal->add(1,2) in the test file for accessing the base class add function....if any please tell me..thanks

Comment: The SUPER shown in my code. It lets perl hunt for the right class through the @ISA.

Answer (score 10):

The main culprit here is `my @ISA`. For inheritance to work, you have to use the package `@ISA` (declare it with `our`).

However, there are some issues in your code beyond that:

1. Please `use parent 'cal'` instead of manipulating `@ISA` yourself.
2. Object-oriented modules have little reason to use `Exporter`.
3. The child1's `new` can be written without reblessing, because the parent's `new` is inherited. The inherited `new` is written in a way that already supports inheritance.
4. Don't give your modules lower-case names, these are reserved for “pragmas”. The `parent` module already exists, and I used it in my 1st point.

Answer (score 7):

`@ISA` must be a public package variable, not a private lexical (`my`). Same for `@EXPORT`. Change `my` to `our` on all those declarations.

Even better, depending on the version of `perl` you have, simplify you life with either the [`parent`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?parent) or [`base`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?base) pragma to load superclasses and to set up the class relationships.

With respect to style, you will avoid considerable confusion if you make the paths to the files that contains your modules’ code match their package names. You would do well to heed a well-established convention described in the [perlmod documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Perl-Modules).

> Module names are also capitalized unless they're functioning as pragmas; pragmas are in effect compiler directives, and are sometimes called “pragmatic modules” (or even “pragmata” if you're a classicist).

The Cal module uses an internal `_initialize` method as described in the [perlobj documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#An-Object-is-Simply-a-Data-Structure) to facilitate inheritance of the constructor.

See below for a complete working example.

### Cal.pm

```
package Cal;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
  my $class=shift;
  my $self=[];
  bless ($self,$class);
  $self->_initialize();
  return $self;
}

sub _initialize {}

sub add {
  my $ref=shift;
  my $a=shift;
  my $b=shift;
  print "This is from parent class\n";
  return ($a+$b);
}

1;
```

### Child1.pm

```
package Child1;

use warnings;
use strict;

use v5.10.1;  # when parent was added to the core
use parent "Cal";

# if you have an older perl, use base instead of parent
# use base "Cal";

sub _initialize {
  my $self=shift;
  push @$self, "I am a " . ref($self) . "!";
}

sub add{
  my $self=shift;
  my($a,$b)=@_;
  print "This is from child class\n";
  return ($a+$b);
}

1;
```

### test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Child1;

my $obj=Child1->new();

my $sum1=$obj->add(1,2);
print "$sum1=sum1\n";

# call the add method in Cal
my $sum2=$obj->Cal::add(1,2);
print "$sum2=sum2\n";

# call add as a class method of Cal, which
# happens to work in this case because Cal::add
# does not use the instance passed to it
my $sum3=Cal->add(1,2);
print "$sum3=sum3\n";
```

Output:

```
This is from child class
3=sum1
This is from parent class
3=sum2
This is from parent class
3=sum3
```

Comment: `base` is superseded by `parent`. The difference between the two pragmata is that `parent` will always `require` the requested module, and that `base` is meant to be used with the outdated `fields` pragma.

Comment: @amon But `parent` is not available on RedHat Linux Enterprise, which is still at v5.8.8, and probably will be for almost ever. So you’d have to add it yourself. However, you really should.

Comment: is there any syntax other than cal->add(1,2) in the test file for accessing the base class add function....if any please tell me..thanks –

Comment: @user2560452 You have at least two ways of doing it with this example. See updated answer.

Comment: It’s far beyond the scope of the question, but the *_init* strategy needs support for SUPER, and even that is a pain with multiple inheritance, where it better to call *EVERY::LAST::_init* from the inherited constructor.